# timespan to datetime conversion format issue to display datetime chart

Tags: c#

I am developing windows forms application and has to display datetime line chart with real time data for every one second.

I have to display time on x-axis in the format of (days:hours:min:sec). The time should be 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:01, 00:00:00:02 etc.

I am taking first response time(system time) as reference time date1. Again after 1 sec, sending request, getting response, capturing  system time as date2 and continuously doing like this. I am getting response timespan by subtracting date2 and date1.

But for datetime chart the x-axis only accepts datetime type variable and has to convert to double using **ToOADate()**.

**Problem:** While converting timespan **00:00:06.2867597** to datetime variable it is converting as **7/25/2016 12:00:06 AM** . But I need the fomat **00:00:06** 
instead of **12:00:06 AM**.

Then only using **ToOADate()**, I will get the correct double value.
Please solve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
 DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now; //  {7/25/2016 8:13:29 PM}  

 DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now; //  {7/25/2016 8:13:30 PM}

 TimeSpan time = date2 .Subtract(date1);  //  {00:00:01.3922821}   

 DateTime  logTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString()); // {7/25/2016 12:00:01 AM}
```

But I need logTime value should be "00:00:01".

Comment: DateTime doesn't keep a display format. Only it's string representation does. Use the `ToString` overload that accept a format provider to display the DateTime value however you want.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want time.ToString()? It kinda looks like you wanted to display the offset from one time to the other, and not convert that back into a DateTime.

Comment: Why put it in a DateTime?

Comment: Because ToOADate() only converts DaeTime value to double. So I converted timespan to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the DateTime then it will automatically show as your system DateTime format. You have to take it as string for desire output this way

```
string  logTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

if you want only time part then

```
 string  logTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: ToOADate() converts DaeTime value to double. So I don't want string format.

Comment: but you can not get specific format without cast it to string, DateTime doesn't have any format it will show as the system format, change system format then you will get change here to

Answer (score 0):

To display your `logTime` as a 24-hour string:

```
logTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

You can't change the logTime DateTime value itself to represent 00:00:01, because they are the same value, you're just changing how you display it.